# Recursive call is not printing the expected combinations of a string in perl

Tags: perl, recursion, perl-module, perl-data-structures

Below program is to print the all possible permutations of the string. I tried this in Perl. But the output is not seems to be the expected one. Could someone please help?

```
print "Enter string ";
chomp( $str = <STDIN> );

$n = length($str);

&combi( $str, 0, ( $n - 1 ) );

sub combi {
    $l = $_[1];
    $r = $_[2];
    if ( $l == $r ) {
        print( $_[0], "\n" );
    }
    else {
        @char = split( "", $_[0] );

        for ( $i = $l; $i <= $r; $i++ ) {
            &swap( $char[ $_[1] ], $char[$i] );
            $res = join( "", @char );
            &combi( $res, ( ( $_[1] ) + 1 ), $r );
            &swap( $char[ $_[1] ], $char[$i] );
        }
    }
}

sub swap {
    $temp = $_[0];
    $_[0] = $_[1];
    $_[1] = $temp;
}
```

Output of the Program:

```
Enter String: abc
abc
acb
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And what's the expected output?

Comment: Missing `use strict; use warnings;`, don't call subs with `&`, avoid global variables.

Comment: Can tidy it up in various ways - none of those are what stops this code working, which is basically because the 'recursion' doesn't actually 'unroll' properly.

Comment: Expected output is ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CBA
CAB , And this is an assignment, I cannot use any written modules or sub routines. I am able to do the same in C or Java but this one is not working in perl.

Comment: Instead of using a subroutine the swap could be written as `( $var1 , $var2 ) = ( $var2 , $var1 ) ;`

Comment: Does it have to be recursive? And does it need to handle a string with duplicate letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding your code, but I *think* your problem is - you're trying do to it quite a heavy weight sort of a way, but importantly - you're not *actually* 'unwinding' the tail of your recursion.

The point of a recursive algorithm is you traverse deep but collate the results.

So I'd approach your problem like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'abcde';

sub combinations {
    my ($string) = @_;

    print "Starting combinations with \"$string\"\n";
    if ( length($string) == 1 ) {
        return ($string);
    }
    my @combinations;
    for my $index ( 0 .. length($string) - 1 ) {
        my @chars = split( //, $string );
        my $firstletter = splice( @chars, $index, 1 );
        print "Keeping: $firstletter combining @chars\n";
        foreach my $combination ( combinations( join( "", @chars ) ) ) {
            print "Got for @chars $combination\n";
            push( @combinations, $firstletter . $combination );
        }
    }
    return (@combinations);
}

print join( "\n", combinations($str) );
```

We have a recursive routine that's 'given' a string. It iterates each of the letters in that string - picking out the 'first letter' and handing the remaining letters to a recursive call to do the same thing.

But then it's 'sticking back together' the results of the call, to make a list of 'results' - since each 'level' of the call should be generating a number of answers, which it then returns to the higher level call, etc.

Note - I've also:

- turned on `strict` and `warnings` - which is really important when writing code.
- not used an `&` prefix in sub calls. That's rarely what you want to be doing.
- not referenced `$_[0]` - as a style point, you should avoid using implicit variables *explicitly* any more than necessary. Name your args, and give them names that's clear what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CPAN module [List::Permutor](http://search.cpan.org/~phoenix/List-Permutor-0.022/Permutor.pm) to print all possible permutations.

For example:

```
use List::Permutor;
my $perm = new List::Permutor qw/ fred barney betty /;
while (my @set = $perm->next) {
  print "One order is @set.\n";
}
```

Another module is [Algorithm::Permute](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Permute/Permute.pm) - Handy and fast permutation with object oriented interface.

Comment: Figured there'd be a module, and was just rummaging to see which one.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I already know there are modules available to permute. But I want core code, Something like normal recursion call which will print all the permutation of the string.

Comment: Why do you want reinvent the wheel?